# Replace(fade) body backgrounds without effecting nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click background is changed to image or color. To do it, for start I made two classes for body:

```
body.bg-color {
    background-color:red;
}
body.bg-img {
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0 fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` I change backgrounds. Thing is that this method fades, in addition to background, also content. What should be done to fade in/out only background?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').addClass('bg-color');
$('.element,#content1,#content2').hide();

    $("#link1").click(function(){
        $('#wrapper').hide();
        $('body').removeClass('bg-color').fadeOut();    
        $('body').addClass('bg-img').fadeIn();
    });

    $("#link2").click(function(){
        $('#wrapper').show();
        $('body').removeClass('bg-img').fadeOut();
        $('body').addClass('bg-color').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying this all to the body tag, use an fixed positioned `<div>` with height and width of 100%, and give that the background color so you can just fade out that element instead of the entire .

Also, you can just toggle one class instead of adding and removing two classes at once.

Eg.

```
#bg{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
}

#bg.bg-img {
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0 fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Just put the following right after the opening body tag:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

Here is your updated JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.element,#content1,#content2').hide();

    $("#link1").click(function(){
        $('#wrapper').hide();
        $('#bg').fadeOut().addClass('bg-img').fadeIn();
    });

    $("#link2").click(function(){
        $('#wrapper').show();
        $('#bg').fadeOut().removeClass('bg-img').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: jetlej, thanks for a try, but this method looks ugly... here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trmu7eyr/  ugliness is caused by fade out and then fade in. Any clue on how to make so that animation is only once?

Comment: ok, I did some changes and now backgrounds do change at once, except animation is almost instant even with 'slow' for .animate. http://jsfiddle.net/trmu7eyr/1/ how to do the change actually slow?

Comment: plus, is there a way to eliminate glitch which is visible if links are clicked often? - background fades in and out for couple of times.